# kill -QUIT: log not getting appended

Tags: java, log4j, monitoring, kill-process

I have a Java process. I am using `log4j` for logging purpose. I have specified in `log4j.xml`, location and name of log file. logging is working fine. I have problem with `kill -3` logs here.

I trying to get process-dump using `kill -QUIT <pid>/ killl -3 <pid>`. I expected the dump generated by `kill -3` to get updated in log file specified in `log4j.xml`.

But it is not happening that way. I need the dump to observer thread statuses. I do not know any other way to get process dump of a running process.

Comment: Not using buffering. I have not specified it explicitly. I do not know how log4j handles flushing by default. Also, the link you pointed to, informs about flushing logs on shutdown. Here, I am not kill the process at all. I am merely using kill -QUIT to get thread dumo.

Comment: @Oleg : I got it why this is happening. Log statements using logger object only going to configured file. Rest everything is redirected to stdout. Kill -QUIT <pid> dump is also getting redirected to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kill -3` should output to stdout, so it should be wherever your stdout goes. If not you could try playing with `-XX:LogFile` JVM option.

Alternative way is `jstack` as suggested by NPE.

Another alternative is to use `jvisualvm` - it will produce stackdump in its nice GUI and you can copy it from there.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. I just look into jStack a little. Are you pointing to this : [http://visualvm.java.net/](http://visualvm.java.net/)

Comment: @SaurabhV yes, but jvisualvm is also part of Oracle JDK, not sure about icedtea/openjdk

Answer (score 1):

> I need the dump to observer thread statuses. I do not know any other way to get process dump of a running process.

You can use [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) for this.

Comment: Got thread dump. How to analyse. Can you please refer some links?